# Why does ASP ListBox take so long to render in AJAX update panel?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax, listbox

I have a problem when updating the source of an ASP ListBox in an AJAX update panel.  When I set the source of the ListBox to a large dataset, I would assume it would take a small amount of time to render due to the number of items.  However, when the DataSource is switched at run-time to a smaller set of items, it takes just as long to clear it.  If you go from a small set of items to a small set of items this is lightning fast.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong.  I'm using the Visual Studio 2008 item template for an `AJAX 1.0-Enabled ASP.NET 2.0 Web Application`.  I downloaded that from [Microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/1/24178c52-ae77-4547-b656-5ad776b1b08f/ASPNETAJAXVS2008.msi).

Here is my code (Full source zip below):

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestingAJAXComboLoadTimes._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListBox ID="myListBox" runat="server" Rows="12" Width="100%" DataTextField="Display"
                DataValueField="Value" AutoPostBack="True" />
            <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Change List" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.vb

```
Partial Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private _ListA As IList(Of MyModel) = New List(Of MyModel)
    Private _ListB As IList(Of MyModel) = New List(Of MyModel)

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        LoadData()
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            myListBox.DataSource = _ListA
            myListBox.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadData()
        For x As Integer = 0 To 5000
            _ListA.Add(New MyModel("testing A - " & x, x))
        Next
        For x As Integer = 0 To 50
            _ListB.Add(New MyModel("testing B - " & x, x))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub SwitchDataSource()
        If IsALoaded Then
            myListBox.DataSource = _ListB
        Else
            myListBox.DataSource = _ListA
        End If
        IsALoaded = Not IsALoaded
        myListBox.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Sub myButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles myButton.Click
        SwitchDataSource()
    End Sub

    Public Property IsALoaded() As Boolean
        Get
            Return CBool(ViewState("IsALoaded"))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            ViewState("IsALoaded") = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

MyModel Class (contained within Default.aspx.vb)

```
Public Class MyModel
    Private _Display As String
    Private _Value As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal display As String, ByVal value As Integer)
        _Display = display
        _Value = value
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property Display() As String
        Get
            Return _Display
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Value
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

I didn't modify the web.config file, but here it is for completeness:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.web>
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <!--
          Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging
          symbols into the compiled page. Because this
          affects performance, set this value to true only
          during development.
    -->
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <!-- Uncomment this line to customize maxJsonLength and add a custom converter -->
                <!--
      <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500">
        <converters>
          <add name="ConvertMe" type="Acme.SubAcme.ConvertMeTypeConverter"/>
        </converters>
      </jsonSerialization>
      -->
                <!-- Uncomment this line to enable the authentication service. Include requireSSL="true" if appropriate. -->
                <!--
        <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true|false"/>
      -->
                <!-- Uncomment these lines to enable the profile service. To allow profile properties to be retrieved
           and modified in ASP.NET AJAX applications, you need to add each property name to the readAccessProperties and
           writeAccessProperties attributes. -->
                <!--
      <profileService enabled="true"
                      readAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2"
                      writeAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2" />
      -->
            </webServices>
            <!--
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
      -->
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is my [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/ajax-listbox-loadtime/) project, and my [Source Code](http://ajax-listbox-loadtime.googlecode.com/files/TestingAJAXListBoxLoadTimes.zip).  Can you tell me why it takes so long to clear the items and set a new list of items?

Thank you,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely culprit is viewstate.

When viewstate is enabled, ASP.NET sends all the `ListBox` data to the client (along with myriad control settings).

Client-side UpdatePanel actions then send the entire viewstate right back to the server. If your dataset is large, that can slow things down significantly, which is probably why going from a large dataset to a small dataset takes so long.

You can speed this up by disabling viewstate for your list box, though that will mean you have to do a lot more in the page by hand - for example, you'll have to rebind the list box on every post.

The article [ASP.NET Simplifies State Management in Web Applications](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/10412/0/page/1) offers an excellent overview of what's going on and what's at stake (see the section titled "Use Viewstate Sparingly" on page three in particular.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I am using view state so that is a possible culprit, however, when I run the same code in Google Chrome, it changes the list without a problem.  It doesn't seem to be a problem with populating the list, it seems to be a problem clearing the list.  Thanks for the link, I'll look into that!

Answer (score 1):

You do realise that UpdatePanel does a full postback don't you? Personally, I don't use it for that reason. You can do lightweight ajax ops on datasources and controls using jQuery and PageMethods.

[This is a nice walkthrough](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)...

Edit: [article on full postback performance issues](http://www.schnieds.com/2008/02/improving-updatepanel-performance-with.html)

`When a PostBack occurs in an UpdatePanel the page’s entire ViewState is passed to the server, updated, and then the updates are passed back down to the ASP.NET page. So the size of your page’s ViewState has a HUGE effect on the performance of your UpdatePanel postbacks.`

Comment: Although I do like jQuery, I can't commit to using it in this scenario.  From MSDN: "If someone clicks the Button in this setup, the Button control will raise a postback event that will be caught by the UpdatePanel control. The UpdatePanel then resubmits the postback event as a partial postback and its content will be asynchronously updated (without the browser fully reloading the page)." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163354.aspx

Comment: You're right, it doesn't 'fully reload the page', it refreshes the content in the panel to give the impression of a partial refresh, however server-side the page does a full execution of its lifecycle. Stick a break point in Page_Load and watch it if you don't believe me. Coupled with viewstate, this is almost certainly your problem. I don't appreciate the down vote either - I haven't provided you with an incorrect answer, whether you liked what I wrote or not :)

Comment: scott- it really is worth trying out the jquery method, compare the two, it's not hard at all, it's maybe an hours work. if you like it you'll have a another tool in your box, if it doesn't make any difference here then i'd be happy to eat humble pie :)